# Select all fields when working with multiple innerjoins

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js

I have a table that looks like this

**participant_coach table**

```
id----nutrition_coach----mental_coach----movement_coach
1 ----       2       ----      5     ----      4
```

**coach table**

```
id----name----email----
2 ----NAME---- @@@@ ----
```

Via an `Inner Join` I want to get the full data for each coach.

Here's my **current query**

```
SELECT
    c1 AS nutrition_coach,
    c2 AS movement_coach,
    c3 AS mental_coach
FROM participant_coaches AS pc 
INNER JOIN coaches AS c1 ON pc.nutrition_coach = c1.id 
INNER JOIN coaches AS c2 ON pc.movement_coach = c2.id 
INNER JOIN coaches AS c3 ON pc.mental_coach = c3.id 
WHERE participant = + participantId
```

This doesn't work and it gives an error that it doesn't know the field `c1`. However when I just want to select 1 property from my c1 table, that does work.

For example, this works

```
SELECT c1.id AS nutrition_coach, 
       c2.id AS movement_coach, 
       c3.id AS mental_coach
```

Returns:

```
mental_coach: 3
movement_coach: 1
nutrition_coach: 2
```

**Is there anyway I can select all the fields from `c1`instead of only 1?**

Here's what I would like to achieve

Response:

```
    {
       mental_coach: {
          id: 1
          name: 'MYNAME'
          email '@@@@'
       }
       movement_coach: {
          ...
       }
       nutrition_coach: {
          ...
       }
   }
```

Comment: To select all the fields from c1, you should use c1.* instead of only c1
But for getting above response , you will have to specify separate alias for each column

Comment: If you need JSON output, then look into using MySQL's JSON API, or you might have to generate this content in your Node.js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id name email

Your query is fine, apart from the `select`.  MySQL doesn't have a notion of "records" that represent the entire row in a table.  You need to list the columns explicitly:

```
SELECT c1.id AS nutrition_coach_id,
       c1.name AS nutrition_coach_name,
       c1.email AS nutrition_coach_email,       
       c2.id AS movement_coach_id,
       c2.name AS movement_coach_name,
       c2.email AS movement_coach_email,
       c3.id AS mental_coach_id,
       c3.name AS mental_coach_name,
       c3.email AS mental_coach_email
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement simply refers to aliases, which represent *tables*, but does not actually state which column you want to use.  Presumably you want to report the names of the three different types of coaches, in which the following should work:

```
SELECT
    c1.name AS nutrition_coach,
    c1.email AS nutrition_coach_email, -- etc. for other fields
    c2.name AS movement_coach,
    c3.name AS mental_coach
FROM participant_coaches AS pc 
INNER JOIN coaches AS c1
    ON pc.nutrition_coach = c1.id 
INNER JOIN coaches AS c2
    ON pc.movement_coach = c2.id 
INNER JOIN coaches AS c3
    ON pc.mental_coach = c3.id 
WHERE participant = <participantId>
```

Comment: Yes I understand that this is my problem. But let's say I have alot of fields and I want to select them all, is there any way to do this, or do I have to type in each fieldname manually? ideally I would be able to do `c1.* AS nutrition_coach` but that didn't work

Comment: Yes, `c1.*` would select all coach fields for the nutrition coach, _but_, you can't really give a column alias to that, because it is generally multiple columns.  In general, using `SELECT *` is bad and should be avoided.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the response I want (as shown in the OP) is not possible via an SQL query?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes it is, see Gordon's answer, who apparently read your question more thoroughly than I did.  Just select whatever columns you want, `id`, `name`, `email`, from the coach table.